# Calculate a new column in rails activerecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an existing query that returns 100,000+ records.

```
dev_results = records.joins("INNER JOIN devices ON (devices.id = snapshots.type_id)")
  .joins("INNER JOIN assets ON (devices.asset_id = assets.id)")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN systems ON (assets.system_id = systems.id)")
  .pluck("devices.hostname, devices.ipaddress, systems.fismaid, assets.is_expired")
```

The Device model has a scope:

```
  scope :dhcp, -> {
joins("INNER JOIN dhcp_cidrs ON (devices.ipaddress <<= dhcp_cidrs.cidr)").where("devices.id NOT IN (?)", Device.reserved.select("devices.id"))
```

}

How do I use Device.dhcp as a subquery to calculate a new column called "is_dhcp" = true if devices.id is in dhcp_ids (otherwise, is_dhcp = false)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgresQL

Answer (score 0):

pluck() supports a wide variety of database commands.  In many DBMS, you could use the IF-THEN-ELSE construct.  In PostgresQL, you must use the CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE-END construct.

First, you can use the model.scope to create the CASE construct as follows:

```
dhcp_device_ids = Device.dhcp.select('devices.id').to_sql
dhcp_calculation = "CASE WHEN (devices.id IN (#{dhcp_device_ids})) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END"
```

Next, you can use this calculation in pluck()

```
.pluck("devices.hostname, devices.ipaddress, systems.fismaid, assets.is_expired, #{dhcp_calculation}")
```